# Declare Security Domain outside of standalone.xml on JBoss 7.1.1

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, jboss, jaas

I'm using Security Domains on JBoss 7 for EJB-Security by Annotations. E.g.

```
@RolesAllowed({"User", "Admin"})
```

Currently I declare the Security Domains in standalone.xml. This is approoriate for small things but I would like to use this kid of security with different Projects on the same JBoss Server. Therefore I'm searching for a way to declare the Security Domains outside of the standalone.xml. I thought of using Deployment Descriptors inside the war-Deployment.

According to [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Security_Guide/chap-Dynamic_Security_Domains.html) this should be possible. but this is for JBoss 5 and seems not to work with JBoss 7.1.1. Starting JBoss throws Exception because of Parser Error. I've also seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087971/how-do-i-specify-which-security-domain-to-use-for-my-web-application-in-jboss-as) but I'm not sure if this is the thing I need. I need to declare new Security Domain with Login Module somewhere outside standalone.xml.

Is there any **simple** solution to store Security domain Declaration and cofiguration in war-Deployment?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible at the moment in a simple way ([related JIRA issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-838)). However, you can use [jboss-as-maven-plugin](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) as a workaround:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>deploy-security-domain</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <pluginManagement>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>7.4.Final</version>
                            <executions>
                              <execution>
                                <id>add-security-domain</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                   <!-- This should work in both "standalone" and "domain" mode -->
                                   <goal>execute-commands</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                  <execute-commands>
                                    <batch>true</batch>
                                    <commands>
                                      <command>/subsystem=security/security-domain=MyDomain:add(cache-type=default)</command>
                                      <command>/subsystem=security/security-domain=MyDomain/authentication=classic:add(login-modules=[{"code"=>"Database","flag"=>"required","module-options"=>[("dsJndiName"=>"java:jboss/datasources/UserDB"),("principalsQuery"=>"select password from users where user_name=?"),("rolesQuery"=>"select role, 'Roles' from user_roles where user_name=?"),("hashAlgorithm"=>"SHA-256"),("hashEncoding"=>"base64")]}]</command>
                                    </commands>
                                  </execute-commands>
                                </configuration>
                              </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

Execution:

```
mvn install -P deploy-security-domain
```

Another option would be a [CLI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/CLI+Recipes) script, that does more or less the same thing. Check out [this](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/blob/master/ejb-security-plus/configure-security-domain.cli) quickstart project for an example.